# Is there a way to determine the version of a file hosted on an HTTP server without downloading the entire file?

Tags: c++, windows, http

Problem statement:
I am designing a file download manager API in C++ on Windows (VS 2010). I need to add a feature where the component will download the file only if a newer version is available on the server in order to avoid an unnecessary download.

Is there a way to determine if a newer version of the file is available on the server without downloading the file itself?

EDIT : I do not have access of / control on the web server to host a web service, etc on the server.

Thank you in advance!

-SF

Comment: `HEAD` request and check the `Last-Modified` header? Or send a request with `If-Modified-Since`?

Comment: I can't use the Last modified header, because the file on the disk is being downloaded using the URLDownloadToFile() call, which is changing it's modified time to the date/time it was downloaded (as opposed to the original last modified time). So, the file on the disk always appears newer.

Comment: The `Last-Modified` header that he referred too is **not** the one on your hard drive, but something returned by the server. See [this blog post](http://blog.mostof.it/what-is-a-http-head-request-good-for-some-uses/) for how you might use it to solve your problem.

Comment: Yes, I understand the last-modified header is the HTTP header, but to know if its newer I will comapre it with the "Last modified" property of the file that already exists on the hard drive (that was previously downlaoded) - and it is this property that is getting set to the date/time that the file was previously downloaded..

Comment: so you'll have store the server-side last-modified time in a separate file/db, or modify your client-side copy's metadata to match the serve-side timestamp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either:

1. send the server a `HEAD` request and look at the response's `Last-Modified` and/or `ETag` header(s). If you are downloading the file for the first time, or if the header value(s) do not match what you have saved from a previous download, then send the server a `GET` command to download the latest file and save the new header value(s) for next time.
2. If you have already downloaded the file once before, you can send the server a "conditional" `GET` request without sending a `HEAD` request first.  To make the request "conitional, either:

   a. Include a `If-Modified-Since` header containing the value of the `Last-Modified` header from the previous download.

   b. Include a `If-Match` header containing the value of the `ETag` header from the previous download.

In a "conditional" `GET` request, if the file has not been modified on the server (the file's current header value(s) still match the `If-` values you request), the server will send a `304 Not Modified` reply without sending any file data. If the file has been modified on the server, or if the server does not support "conditional" `GET` requests, it will send a `200 OK` reply instead with the current file data.

Comment: Marking this as the accepted answer. However, I should I have added in the question that I do have control over when the new versions are posted to the server and I can add additional files to the server. So, what I did end up doing was - to add a text file to the server that would store the version of the latest file on the server. In order to check if a newer version is available, I first download the text file, read the version # and compare it to the version # on the disk and download the file from the server only if its newer.